# Border bootom gradient color

Tags: html, css

```css
.screen{
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 width: 697px;
 height: 12px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 margin: 90px auto;
 background-color: #737373;
}
 .shadow{
  border-bottom: 56px solid #2d2d2d;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 12px;
  width: 591px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="screen">
   <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
```

helo.. i want to change (.shadow) in my css become gradient color. I've been tried to change it but it also change the border-left and right color. I want just the border-bottom color that change.. please help me

Answer (score 1):

you can use transform and a linear gradient.

```css
.screen {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 697px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 90px auto;
  background-color: #737373;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top center;
  top: 100%;
  /* next tune it to your needs */
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(1deg, gray, lightgray, black);
  transform: rotatex(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```